# log4net ThreadContext vs LogicalThreadContext ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, log4net

I'm trying to get `log4net` to log an identifier for all log lines for an action.

To do this I add

```
LogicalThreadContext.Properties["id"] = <unique_id>
```

at the beginning of the request and have `%property{id}` in the `conversionPattern` to output it, which works fine with the tests I did. (On a side note, should that be `ThreadContext` as opposed to `LogicalThreadContext`?)

However, after reading http://piers7.blogspot.com.au/2005/12/log4net-context-problems-with-aspnet.html I'm a bit unsure whether the above approach is incorrect or, given that post was 11 years ago, has `log4net` *fixed* that issue.

So my question is: is the above approach (to store a per-request-id in `log4net` context) correct or how else could you do it?

Comment: Yes, use the logical thread context - "since this is a _logical_ thread context, it will persist across await points, even if a different thread is used to resume the request" - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21341062/43846

Comment: BTW the [issue with LogicalThreadContext](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-437) was fixed for the latest version.